# Setting lower_case_table_names in Travis CI

Tags: mysql, travis-ci

Trying to set lower case table names in MariaDB for a Travis-CI build

```
addons:
  mariadb: '10.1'
```

I've tried

```
  - sudo sed -i '/\[mysqld\]/a lower_case_table_names = 2 ' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
  - sudo service mysql restart
```

and

```
  -  echo "[mysqld]" > .my.cnf
  -  echo "lower_case_table_names = 2" >> .my.cnf
```

If I run :

```
  - mysql --verbose -e  "show variables like 'lower%';" --user=root

--------------
show variables like 'lower%'
--------------
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| lower_case_file_system | OFF   |
| lower_case_table_names | 0     |
+------------------------+-------+
```

And these are the files (run at start before modifications) None have lower_case_table_names in the files (unless I add it)

```
#  - strace mysql 2>&1 | grep cnf
#stat("/etc/my.cnf", 0x7ffef7c8dca0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
#stat("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5232, ...}) = 0
#open("/etc/mysql/my.cnf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
#stat("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=435, ...}) = 0
#open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.cnf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
#stat("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=36, ...}) = 0
#open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
#stat("/etc/mysql/conf.d/tokudb.cnf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=285, ...}) = 0
#open("/etc/mysql/conf.d/tokudb.cnf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
#stat("/home/travis/.my.cnf", 0x7ffef7c8dca0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a doco error somewhere. 
this works:

```
 -  echo "[mysqld]" > $HOME/.my.cnf
 -  echo "lower-case-table-names = 1" >> $HOME/.my.cnf

--------------
show variables like 'lower%'
--------------
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| lower_case_file_system | OFF   |
| lower_case_table_names | 1     |
+------------------------+-------+
```